# Flying within UK without passport as an international student

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, domestic-travel

I am an Indian international student currently studying in the UK on a Tier 4 Student visa. As part of my United States B-1 visa application for an investment bank training program, I am required to go to the US Embassy in Belfast (as the one in London is too busy at the moment).

I am planning to fly to Belfast from Birmingham. While I will have my passport, and thus student visa, with me while going to Belfast, I will obviously need to leave my passport at the US Embassy for processing. Thus I won't have my passport with me while travelling back to Birmingham.

Does domestic airline travel within the United Kingdom itself require me to have my passport? Alternatively, is there any other form of ID I can use which would be acceptable in this case?

Comment: I thought the US gave you a passport custody document to show people.  But that's unconfirmed. If you're a T4 you should have BRP to show and that *should* be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I will readily presume you are flying flybe and not connecting for what otherwise is a 1:10hr flight. flybe [id requirements](http://www.flybe.com/checkin/id-requirements.htm) lists everything acceptable. In particular, University/college ID card is mentioned.

Edit: apparently easyJet flies to Belfast International (flybe flies to Belfast City) and their [requirements](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/travel-documentation) curiously does not mention the University/college ID. However, they mention Valid Government-issued identity card and your biometric residence permit (your Tier 4 visa which you likely [collected at the university](http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/welcome/international/visas/biometricresidencepermits.aspx)) is one.